# Issue Found : Missing "IsMonitoringTool" Flag

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-play-console

After a recent review, we found that your app XYZ is not compliant with one or more of our Developer Program Policies. See below for more information about your app's status and how to correct the issue.
Publishing
Status: Further action required
Status
Your app may be removed from Google Play if you do not resolve the issue(s) by the deadlines listed below.
Issue found: Missing "isMonitoring Tool" flag
We found that your app is not compliant with the Stalkerware and Monitoring Applications policy since the "isMonitoring Tool" flag is not declared in your app's manifest file(s).
Your app may face additional enforcement actions, if you do not resolve this issue by July 13, 2023. Additional notes related to this issue:
• APK 14: Missing "isMonitoring Tool" Flag
Additionally, follow these steps to bring your app into compliance:
• Read the instructions in our Help Center to declare the "isMonitoring Tool" flag value in your app's manifest file(s).
• After making the required updates, deactivate the non-compliant version, upload a compliant version with an incremented version code and make a new submission.
• If you have any concerns with this assessment, please contact our policy support team and provide details.
About the Stalkerware and Monitoring Applications policy
Starting May 2023, your app must be in compliance with Google Play's Stalkerware and Monitoring Applications policy or your app may face additional enforcement actions.
According to Google Play's Stalkerware and Monitoring Applications policy, apps exclusively designed and marketed for monitoring another individual, for example, parents to monitor their children or enterprise management for the monitoring of individual employees, provided they fully comply with the requirements described below are the only acceptable monitoring apps. These apps cannot be used to track anyone else (a spouse, for example) even with their knowledge and permission, regardless if persistent notification is displayed. These apps must use the "isMonitoring Tool" metadata flag in their manifest file to appropriately designate themselves as monitoring apps.
Monitoring apps must provide adequate prominent disclosure and obtain consent as required by the